# Перевести строку в число не использую стандартные функции

Tags: c++, строки, int

Мне нужно написать программу которая переводит строку в число. Например: вводится строка `"1234"` на выход получаем число `1234`, все было бы проще если бы мне можно было юзать простые функции, такие как - `atoi()`

Comment: *"Хэлпуйте"* - что, в переводе, означает *"работать негры, солнце еще высоко"*

Comment: Это означает _натолкните на мысль_ , я не заставляю ВАС отвечать на мой вопрос

Comment: Наталкиваю: 1234 = ((1*10+2)*10+3)*10+4... И еще: 1 == '1' - '0',  5 == '5' - '0'...

Comment: *"Мне надо"* - это не вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я решил эту задачу)
Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main() {
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    int num = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        num = num * 10 + str[i] - '0';
    }
    cout << num << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```